# How to show/hide image in intervals?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery to use it's hide function but I can't seem to get it to work. The image is normally set to a scale of 0 0 0, and after a period of time, the scale changes to 1 1 1 (so, image becomes visible). I want to do this on an interval and can use setInterval for that. However, I also want to hide the image while inside that same interval. So, it becomes visible and then invisible on a loop, basically. Here is the code:

```
 <script>
      function PopUp(scale) {
        var indicator = document.getElementById('FeelIndicator');
        indicator.setAttribute('scale', '1 1 1');
          $("#FeelIndicator").hide(8 * 1000) }
      setInterval(PopUp, 10 * 1000); 
</script>
```

As of now, the indicator does pop up after 10 seconds, but never becomes hidden. I don't get an error message in the console, but I'm guessing that I'm not using the jQuery code correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

edit: Thank you Jaromanda. I've edited the code but it still doesn't seem work.

Muhammad, I just want it to appear for a few seconds and then disappear. It will also disappear if the user clicks on the image but I'm not worried about figuring out that code.

Comment: `#indicator` ... but `getElementById('FeelIndicator');` ... do you have an element with `id="indicator"` or should it be `#FeelIndicator`

Comment: so , are you trying to animate it like a blink or want to display it once there is an error and then hide it back?

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery/javascript selectors don't match.

Assuming the actual element Id is `#FeelIndicator`:

`$('#FeelIndicator').hide(8 * 1000)`

instead of:

`$('#indicator').hide(8 * 1000)`